# How do i stretch the width of the menu to full width in html5

Tags: css, html

Just playing around with html5 and css and i got hooked trying to give a full width menu.

I took me hours trying to figure out where the problems lie but could not get it to work.

I would need your help guys.

Here is my html5 and css codes:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
}
header{
 
}
.nav {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: 900
 width: 100%;
 background:#34495E;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-list {

}

.nav-item {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
}

.nav-item a {
  display:block;
  padding:20px 20px;
  color:#FFF;
  width: 100%; 
}

ul li.selected {
 background: #fff;
}

ul li.selected a {
 color: #384047;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background: tomato;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    width:100%;
  }
  .nav-item {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>This is the index</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">  
 <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <!--<div id="logo" class="">
         <h1>XYZ</h1>
        </div> -->
  <nav class="nav">   
   <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>

 <article>
    
 </article>

 <footer>
  Copyright | XYZ | 2016.
 </footer>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo - `font-weight: 900(;)` -> semicolon is missing. Also, you don't need to use `inline-block` for that element, as it's only one.

Comment: @ vucko, many thanks. Immediately i fixed the typo in font weight, it works.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
}
header{
 
}
.nav {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: 900;
 width: 100%;
 background:#34495E;
 text-align: center;
}

.nav-list {

}

.nav-item {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
}

.nav-item a {
  display:block;
  padding:20px 20px;
  color:#FFF;
  width: 100%; 
}

ul li.selected {
 background: #fff;
}

ul li.selected a {
 color: #384047;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background: tomato;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    width:100%;
  }
  .nav-item {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>This is the index</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">  
 <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

 <header>
  <!--<div id="logo" class="">
         <h1>XYZ</h1>
        </div> -->
  <nav class="nav">   
   <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>

 <article>
    
 </article>

 <footer>
  Copyright | XYZ | 2016.
 </footer>
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here it works. You only missed a semicolon (;)

Comment: Why does it work? Can you please explain what you did instead of just giving him the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}
header{
    width:100%;
}
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 100%;
    background:#34495E;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav-list {

}

.nav-item {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}

.nav-item a {
  display:block;
  padding:20px 20px;
  color:#FFF;
  width: 100%; 
}

ul li.selected {
    background: #fff;
}

ul li.selected a {
    color: #384047;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  background: tomato;

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    width:100%;
  }
  .nav-item {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

you didn't close `font-weight:900` with a `;`

https://jsfiddle.net/uxrfxwd7/